# MySQL squash empty fields when GROUPing BY

Tags: mysql

If I have a MySQL table like so, where there are two rows for a specific email address, each incomplete, but together making a full record:

```
+-------+-------+------------------+
| fname | sname | email            |
+-------+-------+------------------+
| John  |       | john@smith.com   |
|       | Smith | john@smith.com   |
| Sue   | Jones | sue@jones.com    |
| Jim   |       | jim@jim.com      |
+-------+-------+------------------+
```

I can run the following query with `GROUP BY` to return distinct email addresses and receive EITHER the `fname` or `sname` of John Smith:

```
SELECT *
FROM users
GROUP BY email

+-------+-------+------------------+
| fname | sname | email            |
+-------+-------+------------------+
| John  |       | john@smith.com   |
| Sue   | Jones | sue@jones.com    |
| Jim   |       | jim@jim.com      |
+-------+-------+------------------+
```

Is there any way to merge the blank fields in the rows (similar to how `COALESCE` works with `null` when `SELECT`ing) which would instead give me the following result?

```
+-------+-------+------------------+
| fname | sname | email            |
+-------+-------+------------------+
| John  | Smith | john@smith.com   |
| Sue   | Jones | sue@jones.com    |
| Jim   |       | jim@jim.com      |
+-------+-------+------------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `max()` to get the "highest" value for each email

```
SELECT email, 
       max(fname) as fname, 
       max(sname) as sname
FROM users
GROUP BY email
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `max()` aggregate function to return the highest non-null value for a group. You should use it for both columns (your current sql query is against the sql standards anyway because you have fields in the select list that are neither in the group by list, nor are subject of an aggregate function):

```
SELECT email, max(fname) as fname, max(sname) as sname
FROM users
GROUP BY email
```